# C++ State Machine

Tags: c++, state-machine

Below might be an implementation of a simple State Machine in C++. The class **Tokenizer** maintains the "tokenization state variables", and returns tokens, like HTML tags from a stream of characters.

Should there be any reason to move out the functions handle_xxx() out of Tokenizer class;

And if yes, then why & how?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Token;
class CharacterReader;

class Tokenizer {
    TokenizerState current_state;
    CharacterReader r;
    std:map<TokenizerState, void (Tokenizer::*pmf)()> stateMap;

public:
    // Tokenizer States
    typedef enum { INITIAL = 0, STATE_1, STATE_2, END } TokenizerState;

    // State Handlers
    void handle_Initial();
    void handle_State_1();
    void handle_State_2();
    // 20 more states before END...
    void handle_End();

    Tokenizer(String text_to_tokenize) 
    {
        stateMap[INITIAL] = handle_Initial;
        stateMap[STATE_1] = handle_State_1;
        stateMap[STATE_2] = handle_State_2;
        stateMap[END] = handle_End;

        current_state = TokenizerState::INITIAL;
        r.set(text_to_tokenize);
    }

    void switchState(TokenizerState s) { current_state = s; }

    void run() {
        while (current_state!=TokenizerState::END) {
            Token token = stateMap[current_state]();
            // do something with the Token
        }
    }
};

void Tokenizer::handle_Initial() {
}

void Tokenizer::handle_State_1() {
    char c = r++;
    switch(c) {
        case 'a':
                break;
        case 'b':
                ts.switchState(Tokenizer::TokenizerState::STATE_2);
    }
}

void Tokenizer::handle_State_2() {
}

void Tokenizer::handle_End() {
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this is a _'typical implementation of a State Machine in C++'_?? Way off! Seriously, not for my understanding of how to implement FSMs! Better approaches IMHO: [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern), or as abstraction [STTCL](https://github.com/makulik/sttcl).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ . Edited... not typical .. a novice approach ...

Comment: Sorry, doesn't convince me still, also my pointers are still valid regarding to find an appropriate solution ..

Comment: There are many same such state machine implementations for simple task like this when I googled... my intent is that this is very much C like approach. whats the better way to do it in C++, apart from using those heavyweight State Patterns...

Comment: State Pattern isn't heavyweight! It's just the opposite, best case is, that state classes only provide behavior and no intrinsic state at all, thus are [**flyweight**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). Study the patterns, before you judge!! `switch/case` won't satisfy you on the mid-/long-term!

Comment: From Wiki .. A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory use. If that's what you understood by my use of the word "heavyweight", then its not. I just used it it in the general sense... like all that heavy stuff ...

Comment: Questionable, what _'all that heavy stuff'_ should mean? What's actually **heavy** about it? It clarifies much more, than it obfuscates behavior as switch/case idiom does IMHO. What are you actually bothering about? Understanding it?

Comment: Downvoters .. please share you insight also as to what is so wrong with the question. We are here to share knowledge. Your comments, pointers, suggestions for improvement might help those also who move from C to C++ and might have been using the same logic to implement state machines. Down votes won't help.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sir!!! You have questioned everything about my question !! :-) or whatever I said. :-) Usually I am pretty much clear about my intent ... bad miss today though :)

Comment: Yeah, may be it's time for you to get in charge answering all these questions I gave you. For simple tokenizing/protocol state machines there are other solutions available that are more appropriate than the general patterns I linked to. From an abstract point of view they just provide a variation, but from practice, it makes a big difference. One of such frameworks is e.g. [boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html), or use an external tool like [flex](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Cxx.html).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the best way would be to move out all the `handle_XXX()` (read *XXX* as a state machine triggering event) methods to a separate interface, and have distinct implementations for these for each of the identified states. The implementation of the `handle_XXX()` methods, may receive a reference to the current state machine instance, and manipulate / operate on it (including triggering a state change).

That's what is proposed in the commonly known [**State Pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

One of the present flaws I see in your implementation is, that you miss to map the actual events to dispatch them to a distinct handler.

It's a bit pointless to proceed with a comprehensible code sample upon this base you gave. I hope you get my pointers right.

Answer (score -1):

Why not define a TokenizerHandler class, and pass its instance(s) into the Tokenzier class? The same way to reference member functions may still work.